# How to trigger dependabot when closing its PR?

Tags: git, github, dependabot

This has happened:

We got a PR from dependabot which we wanted to adress, We decided to shift git strategy by using rebase and the PR that dependabot created was following the old merge startegy.

To get arround this we would manauly need to rebase, resolve conflicts and squash commits.

We then closed the PR from dependabot and got the following:

> "OK, I won't notify you again about this release, but will get in
> touch when a new version is available. If you'd rather skip all
> updates until the next major or minor version, let me know by
> commenting @dependabot ignore this major version or @dependabot ignore
> this minor version. You can also ignore all major, minor, or patch
> releases for a dependency by adding an ignore condition with the
> desired update_types to your config file.
>
> If you change your mind, just re-open this PR and I'll resolve any
> conflicts on it."

What we want:

Dependabot to create a brand new PR from scratch regarding the same dependency update but now from a fresh git history, if we open and call the recreate command it can not resolve by its own and forces us to do it.

Is there a possibility to retrigger dependabot to create a brand new PR for same dependency?

Cheers

Comment: Did you try `@dependabot rebase`?